# Select directly into hierarchical user type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Is it possible to do a select directly into a hierarchical user type?

Imagine a table structure like this:

```
PARENT
------
ID
NAME

CHILD
-----
ID
PARENT_ID
NAME
```

Additionally, I have user types like this:

```
create or replace type child_item as object
(
  ID NUMBER(10),
  NAME VARCHAR(255)
);

create or replace type children_table as table of child_item;

create or replace type parent_item as object
(
  ID NUMBER(10),
  NAME VARCHAR(255),
  CHILDREN CHILDREN_TABLE
);

create or replace type parent_table as table of parent_item;
```

And a statement like this:

```
select * from parent p inner join child c on p.id = c.parent_id;
```

Now, I want the result of that statement to be in an object of type `parent_table`. Is this somehow possible without the use of a complex `FOR` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [COLLECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions031.htm#SQLRF06304):

```
SELECT parent_item(p.ID, 
                   p.NAME, 
                   CAST(COLLECT(child_item(c.id, c.NAME)) AS children_table))
  FROM PARENT p
 INNER JOIN child c ON p.id = c.parent_id
 GROUP BY p.ID, p.NAME
```

This will return a list of `PARENT_ITEM` that you can BULK COLLECT into a `PARENT_TABLE`.

You could use COLLECT again in an outer query to get a PARENT_TABLE directly:

```
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(parents) AS parent_table)
  FROM (SELECT parent_item(p.ID, 
                           p.NAME, 
                           CAST(COLLECT(child_item(c.id, c.NAME)) 
                             AS children_table)
                          ) parents
          FROM PARENT p
         INNER JOIN child c ON p.id = c.parent_id
         GROUP BY p.ID, p.NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Assuming there are 3 items in `PARENT` and each of them has three related items in `CHILDREN`. Will this return 3 `parent_item`s with 3 `child_item`s each or will this return 9 `parent_item`s with 1 `child_item` each? I am asking, because the result of my sample query in the question would be 9 rows.

Comment: To answer my own question: It returns 3 parents with 3 children each.

Comment: Nice answer - my immediate reaction to this question was that it cannot be done, but luckily I stand corrected and have learned something today.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CAST(MULTISET())`:

```
with data as (
select p.id pid,p.name pname,cast(multiset(select c.id,c.name 
from child c where c.parent_id=p.id) AS children_table) ct
from parent p
)
select cast(multiset(select pid,pname,ct from data) as parent_table) 
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks great so far. But it will not result in an object of type `parent_table`. How would I do this? I assume I would need to somehow cast the complete result to `parent_table` and select it into a variable of that type, but I am not entirely sure how this cast would look like. Maybe something like this? `select cast(multiset(select p.id, p.name, cast(multiset(...) as children_table)) as parent_table) into variable from dual`

Comment: Thanks! However, I accepted Vincent's solution, because it allows me to use my already existing statements with the joins.